# What is an effective method to display the username of the User who created posts and comments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Right now my posts have a `user_id`:

```
def create

@post = @user.posts.new(post_params)


@post.user_id = current_user.id

if @post.save
  redirect_to @post
else
  render :new
end
end
```

I link to the user's username like this in my show view:

```
<%= @user.username %>
```

**show action:**

```
def show
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
@user = User.find(@post.user_id)
end
```

When I visit my show view nothing shows up but I do not get an error message.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: `@post.user_id = current_user.id` is redundant. It will already be set to `@user.id`, that's the whole reason for doing `@user.posts.new` instead of `Post.new`. Is `@user` not the same as `current_user`? If not, I can't see why you'd be changing the user who owns the post?

Comment: Wouldn't current_user refer to the currently logged in User when using it in the views or am I completely wrong?

Comment: What error message do you get when you visit show view? Also, if you set up has_many - belongs_to association between `User` and `Post` models, you can access user like this: `@user = @post.user`

Comment: @JoeSmith Yes, but isn't that the user who is creating the post? How can a user create a post, when he's not the current user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the better way is show the user through the post:

```
<%= @post.user.username %>
```

This is straightforward and no doubt that I'm showing the user of the post, not the current_user or any other.

To show this way you must do some eager load to prevent duplicate db calls:

```
def show
  @post = Post.includes(:user).find(params[:id])
end
```

You must avoid that: `params.require(:post).permit(:user_id)`, it's a security issue. why? Because you must only call permit on params that you expect your user send. Then assuming current_user returns the user logged:

```
def create
  @post = Posts.new(post_params)
  @post.user_id = current_user.id
  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render :new
  end
end

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:only_post_data_that_user_send)
end
```

I thing this must do the trick. If not work, be sure current_user must be the user logged, after that think if post.user_id can be nil, if not remove bad records from db, and add a validation to Post. If it can be nil use: `@post.user.try(:username)`.

Comment: How would you show the username in the index action/view, would make @post a class variable be the way to do this?

Comment: The same way `@posts = Post.includes(:user).page(params[:page])`, more [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations). At index view: `<%= render @posts %>` and at post partial `<%= post.user.username %>` without the at symbol. See how [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections).

Comment: I didn't even define @posts like that for the index view and it still works?

Comment: Yes, it works. But, it's a n + 1 issue. Please read the first 'here' link at the previous comment.